# How to Calculate age by birthday, including month, day & Year?

Tags: visual-foxpro

What is the code for calculating the age by birthday?

How to Calculate age by birthday, including month, day & Year?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (DATE()-bdate)/365 FROM table1
```

where bdate is Date or DateTime field containing date of birth.

Answer (score 0):

One of these articles or a combination of both should give you what you need:

http://www.tomorrowssolutionsllc.com/Articles/Calculate%20Age%20in%20Years%20and%20Months.pdf

http://www.tomorrowssolutionsllc.com/Articles/Computing%20Exact%20Age.PDF